# SQL Server subquery for count in 2nd table

Tags: sql-server, correlated-subquery

I would like to add the count result of a 2nd query to the result set which queries the 1st table and connect this subquery with the ID of the 1st Table result. This simplified code explains it:

```
Select 
    ID_Field_Table1, 
    (Select Count(x) 
     From Table2 
     Where ID_Field_Table2 = ID_Field_Table1) As mycount 
From Table1
```

What is the correct syntax?
Thanks

This code is simplified but the construction is the same. In my DB the ID_Field_Table2 and ID_Field_Table1 have the same name (let's say ID_Field). If I use this same Name, the SubQuery goes like "...Where ID_Field = ID_Field.." and this always Returns a Reslut, because it is not connecting the queries ("Select a Where x = x" returns any record in the table 2).

```
Select 
    ID_Field AS ID1, 
    (Select Count(x) 
     From Table2 
     Where ID_Field = ID1) As mycount 
From Table1
```

It just returns an error, saying that ID1 does not exist.

1. When I use the original name of the columns (which are the same), the result is wrong
2. When I us an alias, an error occurs

So I think the query is wrong at all.

Comment: Your query seems ok to me. What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't use an alias defined in the select clause, but you can use the aliases defined in the from clause:

```
Select 
    ID_Field AS ID1, 
    (Select Count(x) 
     From Table2 
     Where ID_Field = t1.ID_Field) As mycount 
From Table1 t1
```

You can also do it without an alias, since the sub query is for a different table:

```
Select 
    ID_Field AS ID1, 
    (Select Count(x) 
     From Table2 
     Where ID_Field = Table1.ID_Field) As mycount 
From Table1
```

However, I suspect a query using left join to a derived table as suggested in esta's answer would have better performance.

Comment: That works. Thank you. Now that I see it, I wonder why I didn't try this before ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Select 
    Table1.ID_Field_Table1,
    T2.MYCOUNT    
From Table1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID_Field_Table2, COUNT(x) AS MYCOUNT FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY ID_FIELD_TABLE2) T2 ON T2.ID_Field_Table2=Table1.ID_Field_Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This query once it may help you.

```
Select ID_Field_Table1,COUNT_NBR 
cross apply 
(
Select Count(x) as COUNT_NBR
     From Table2 
     Where ID_Field_Table2 = ID_Field_Table1
     group by ID_Field_Table1
) As mycount 
From Table1
```